# NSolve not solving simple couple of paired equations

Tags: equation-solving

Both Solve[] and NSolve[] seem to be unable to solve this simple system of two equations:
$$ \sin(\phi_1) + 0.6 \sin(\phi_1 + \phi_2) ==0,$$
$$ 0.1\sin(\phi_2) + 0.6 \sin(\phi_1 + \phi_2) ==0,$$
with $\phi_1,\phi_2 \in (-\pi,\pi )$.

```
NSolve[{Sin[ϕ1] + 0.6` Sin[ϕ1 + ϕ2] == 
0 && ϕ1 > -π && ϕ1 <= π, 
0.1` Sin[ϕ2] + 0.6` Sin[ϕ1 + ϕ2] == 
0 && ϕ2 > -π && ϕ2 <= π}, {ϕ1, ϕ2}]
```

The output simply prints the input. Am I doing something wrong?
I know from graphs that there are indeed solutions

Comment: Try: `Reduce[{Sin[\[Phi]1] + 6/10*Sin[\[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2] == 0 && 
   1/10*Sin[\[Phi]2] + 6/10*Sin[\[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2] == 
    0 && -Pi < \[Phi]1 < Pi && -Pi < \[Phi]2 < 
    Pi}, {\[Phi]1, \[Phi]2}]`? `Solve` and `NSolve` deals primarily with linear and polynomial equations.One solution: `ContourPlot[{Sin[\[Phi]1] + 6/10*Sin[\[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2] == 0, 
  1/10*Sin[\[Phi]2] + 6/10*Sin[\[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2] == 
   0}, {\[Phi]1, -Pi, Pi}, {\[Phi]2, -Pi, Pi}]`

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, Reduce only gives one solution (0,0) whereas I need to access all solutions, moreover in an automatised way as I'm looping over different values for the coefficients of the Sine functions.

Comment: All solution: `Reduce[{Sin[\[Phi]1] + 6/10*Sin[\[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2] == 0 && 
   1/10*Sin[\[Phi]2] + 6/10*Sin[\[Phi]1 + \[Phi]2] == 
    0 && -Pi < \[Phi]1 <= Pi && -Pi < \[Phi]2 <= 
    Pi}, {\[Phi]1, \[Phi]2}]`?

Comment: ah, of course..

Comment: sorry, Is there a way to obtain the solutions as a paired list, instead of
(\[Phi]1 == 
    0 && (\[Phi]2 == 
      0 || \[Phi]2 == \[Pi])) || (\[Phi]1 == \[Pi] && (\[Phi]2 == \
\[Pi] || \[Phi]2 == 0))

Comment: Yes try: `Solve[%]`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Marius' comment, you can use [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) with `Method -> Reduce`:

```
Solve[
    {
    Sin[ϕ1] + 0.6 Sin[ϕ1 + ϕ2] == 0 && ϕ1 > -π && ϕ1 <= π, 
    0.1 Sin[ϕ2] + 0.6 Sin[ϕ1 + ϕ2] == 0 && ϕ2 > -π && ϕ2 <= π
    },
    {ϕ1, ϕ2},
    Method->Reduce
]
```

> Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.
>
> {{ϕ1 -> 0, ϕ2 -> 0}, {ϕ1 -> 0, ϕ2 -> 3.14159}, {ϕ1 ->
>       3.14159, ϕ2 -> 0}, {ϕ1 -> 3.14159, ϕ2 -> 3.14159}}

Comment: Why not use $\dfrac{1}{10}$ and $\dfrac{6}{10}$ instead to remove the error message?